# Error while downloading directory in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins

Through the Jenkins parameters, I set the variables for the application version and the folder where the version should be taken from - VERSION_CURR and DIR_VER_CURR. I cannot figure out what is wrong in my script.

> string parameter in Jenkins:
>
> ```
> VERSION_CURR = 6.2.1.1
>
> DIR_VER_CURR = 6.2.1
> ```

```
if [ -z "$VERSION_CURR" ]; then 
            VERSION_CURR="$(sshpass -p $globalPass ssh user@192.168.194.69 'cd /home/fesb/Stand/upload && ls fesb-'$versionPref'*.tar.gz -t | head -1')"
        
else if [ -z "$DIR_VER_CURR" ]; then
        PATH_VER_CURR="fesb-$VERSION_CURR.tar.gz"  
    
        else VERSION_CURR="$DIR_VER_CURR/fesb-$VERSION_CURR.tar.gz"
    fi
fi


echo 'Current version = ' $VERSION_CURR


echo *****download version*****

cd /home/fesb/Stand/upload
sshpass -p $globalPass scp user@192.168.194.69:/home/fesb/Stand/upload/$VERSION_CURR
```

If $ VERSION_CURR = 0 and $ DIR_VER_CURR = 0, then the latest version is taken from the upload folder

exception: Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Comment: `$VERSION_CURR = 6.2.1.1`
`$DIR_VER_CURR = 6.2.1`
this is not the way to set vars in bash

Comment: these are string parameters in jenkins

Comment: All looks correct, you have to test it in real environment, add echos like `echo $VERSION_CURR $DIR_VER_CURR` and `$PATH_VER_CURR` or run with `bash -x`